# How to validate hdfs result with python regex to find out if it is a folder, file or non exist

Tags: python, regex

I have a str which is the result of hdfs command to show, for a given path, if it is a folder, or a file, or doesn't exist, here are examples:

str_file:

```
-rw-rw----+  3 jdoe clouderausersdev   12267543 2018-02-05 16:41 hdfs://nameservice1/client/abc/part-00000-994917013a6a-c000.snappy.parquet
```

str_folder:

```
Found 3 items
-rw-rw----+  3 jdoe clouderausersdev          0 2018-02-05 16:41 hdfs://nameservice1/client/abc/_SUCCESS
-rw-rw----+  3 jdoe clouderausersdev   12267543 2018-02-05 16:41 hdfs://nameservice1/client/abc/part-00000-994917013a6a-c000.snappy.parquet
-rw-rw----+  3 jdoe clouderausersdev   12267543 2018-02-05 16:41 hdfs://nameservice1/client/abc/part-00001-994917013a6a-c000.snappy.parquet
-rw-rw----+  3 jdoe clouderausersdev   12267543 2018-02-05 16:41 hdfs://nameservice1/client/abc/part-00002-994917013a6a-c000.snappy.parquet
```

str_nonexist:

```
ls: `hdfs://nameservice1/client/abc/part-00000.parqu': No such file or directory
```

Now that I want to know the result with regex check, here is the problem:

```
import re

regex_folder = "Found [1-9]\d items"
regex_file = ".parquet"
regex_error = "No such file"
```

Testing result is as below:

[image]

So, how do I tell the difference between m and m1? apparently m means no finding while m1 means there is match.

Eventually I need to tell the three scenarios: folder, file, nonexist

Thank you very much.

Update (as per Филип Димитровски):

Still now working:m1 should show a match and m should not.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your regex `Found [1-9]\d items` means you want to search for `Found xy items` where `x` is a digit between 1 and 9, and `y` is a digit between 0 and 9. This is problematic, and I assume it is not what you want. If you want to match one or more digits, just use `\d+`. You may use [online regex testers](https://regex101.com/) to debug such issues.

The second problem is the misuse of string literals. When working with regular expressions in Python, you should always use raw string literals, which start with the letter 'r'.

- This is **good**: `re.search(r'regex \d here', ..`
- This is **bad**: `re.search('regex \d here', ..`.

Once you fix those, `result = re.search(r'Found \d+ items', some_string)` will work. To check if you have don't have any matches, you can compare the result with `None`.  If the result is not `None`, it will be a [match object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#match-objects). Note: *when an expression evaluates to None its result is blank and it is not displayed in the interpreter.*

Here's a working demo:

```
import re

str1 = 'ffff'
str2 = 'Found 3 items ffff'
reg_folder = r'Found ([1-9]\d*) items'
if re.search(reg_folder, str1) is None:
    print('Nothing found in str1')

result = re.search(reg_folder, str2)
if result is not None:
    num = result[1]
    print('Found the number: {}'.format(num))
else:
    print('Nothing found in str2')
```

Also, keep in mind that regular expressions are not good at parsing human-friendly messages and there may be libraries for HDFS instead of parsing raw output.

Comment: Thank you but still same, updated to the original post

Comment: @mdivk Use `reg_folder=r'Found \d+ items'`

Comment: The reason of 'Found [1-9]\d items' is the number would always starts with non-0 number

Comment: ok, so now m==m1 returns false, how do I write the python code to check if there is a match? Thanks.

Comment: @mdivk Then, use `reg_folder = r'Found [1-9]\d* items'`

Comment: Thanks, so now m==m1 returns false, how do I write the python code to check if there is a match?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183144/discussion-between---and-mdivk).